# Office apps crash on Remote Desktop Server

Tags: microsoft-office-365, remote-desktop-services

I’m having a problem on a couple of Remote Desktop Servers.
When certain users (not all of them) open any Excel, Outlook, PowerPoint or Word (Office 2016), the application immediately crashes.
The Event-Log shows something like this:
WINDWORD.EXE
16.0.7766.2092
KERNELBASE.dll

I set up a new profile for one of the users having this problem, and it solved the issue. However, I would like to avoid setting up new profiles for all of the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the solution. Our firewall is doing some type of SSL decryption. We excluded the following domains from SSL decryption:

*.microsoftonline.*, *.windows.net, *.msecnd.net, *.microsoftonline-p.com, account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com, * .officeapps.*, *.aadrm.*, *.live.com, * .telemetry.*

I don’t know if each of those is necessary, however these where the ones I captured during the startup of office programs.